# using ,htaccess redirect example.com?id=12 to example.com/index.php?id=12

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect "example.com?pid=12" to "example.com/index.php?pid=12" using .htaccess

I have written following in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid [NC]
RewriteRule ^ example.com/index.php\?$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it is not appending the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=\d+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

Query string is automatically carried over to the target.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Query String Append flag `[QSA]` in the `RewriteRule` because you are modifying the query string with a "?"

More info: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString